# How to Serialize Object to json in Ruby

Tags: ruby, json

I am learning Ruby and am wondering how to serialize a ruby object to json.  I am cool using ActiveSupport or any other gems, what is the best way to to this?  The following approach doesn't work and fails with

```
BinaryTree.rb:4:in `require': no such file to load -- json (LoadError)
```

My question is, what do I install and what require statements would I need to use?

```
 #!/usr/bin/env ruby

 require 'pp'
 require 'json'

 class BinaryTree

     attr_accessor :key, :value, :left, :right

     def initialize(key=nil,value=nil, left=nil, right=nil)
         @key, @value, @left, @right = key, value, left, right
     end

     def insert(key,value)
         if @key.nil?
             @key = key
             return @value = value
         end

         if key == @key
             return @value = value
         end

         if key > @key
             if @right.nil?
                 @right = BinaryTree.new
             end
             return @right.insert(key, value)
         end

         if @left.nil?
             @left = BinaryTree.new
         end
         return @left.insert(key, value)
     end
 end

 if __FILE__ == $0
     bt = BinaryTree.new
     bt.insert(5,2)
     bt.insert(4,5)
     bt.insert(6,3)
     bt.insert(9,7)
     bt.insert(8,9)
     pp bt
     puts JSON.encode(bt)
end
```

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4569329/serialize-ruby-object-to-json-and-back and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4464050/ruby-objects-and-json-serialization-without-rails

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the `json` gem installed? If not, you'd need to ensure you install that using `gem install json` first. Once installed, you should be able to do something like the following:

```
File.open('output_file', 'w') do |f|
  f.write(JSON.encode(bt))
end
```

Using the `File.open` API with a block is convenient since it will `#close` the file instance afterward.

**Update**

If you're on Ruby 1.8 or earlier, you must set up Rubygems first, using the following:

```
require 'rubygems'
gem 'json'
require 'json'

puts ['test'].to_json
```

Comment: I think that I do, but maybe its not being found?  Is there an include type of argument I need to pass to the interpreter?
`$ sudo gem install json
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed json-1.7.7
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for json-1.7.7...
Installing RDoc documentation for json-1.7.7...

$ ruby BinaryTree.rb
BinaryTree.rb:4:in `require': no such file to load -- json (LoadError)
 from BinaryTree.rb:4
`

Comment: Oh, are you on Ruby 1.8? If so, you'll need to manually `require 'rubygems'` and call `gem 'json'` first. I've updated my answer with details.