# How to populate a DB using and JSON file in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, database, api, migrating

So, before asking, I must say I am absolutely new to web programming. I have started studying 2 days ago and my only programming experience is with C  language. I am trying to learn ruby on rails through some exercises. This means that I don't know almost anything about the syntax, but I am getting it little by little.

So, the current exercise is: to fetch a JSON file, obtained from a website API, and store its data in a model, which in turn I must display on a table.

Because I have a C experience, I understand this problem as something like 1. creating a new structure, 2. creating a vector for this structure, 3. reading data from a file a storing it in this vector, 4.printing the data. All that is done through writing lines of code in a single .c file and then running it in my terminal.

But things don't seem to work in this manner with rails language. I have read some codes with similar problems but I'm just not quite sure where to write them. I mean, in which files/directories? Because in C we don't have such a thing as multiple files and folders (we just write a one-page program). I am kind of lost.

If someone can help with some general steps, as where/why/what to write, I would be very grateful! There is no need to be completely specific just some overall ideas would be fantastic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that you have obtained a JSON *file* that contains one single JSON *object* and that you have read it from the file into memory. Your question does not clarify whether this would already be an issue, so I assume that you can do this conversion (string in file to live object). If not, take a look at this: [Serialize Ruby object to JSON and back?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4569329/serialize-ruby-object-to-json-and-back)

The next thing to do is to turn it into an in-memory ActiveRecord object. Assuming that the json object only contains key/value pairs that are valid for the model in question, you can do it as simple as this:

```
ar_object = MyModel.new(json_object.to_hash)
```

Then, save it to the database (which requires a database table that corresponds to you AR model and that has a correct column for each of the keys in your json object:

```
ar_object.save
```

Then, when a browser calls the index page of the AR model, e.g. http://localhost:3000/my_models.html, use your controller's index method to fetch all instances of the model from the database:

```
class MyModelsController < ApplicationController

   def index
     @objects = MyModell.all
     # rails will render /app/views/my_models/index.html.erb by default
   end

end
```

Then in app/views/my_models/index.html.erb:

```
<table>
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>Col 1 name</th>
       <th>Col 2 name</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <% for object in @objects do %>
       <tr>
         <td><%= object.col_1 %>
         <td><%= object.col_2 %>
       </tr>
     <% end %>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

The HTML might of course look different, depending on your model's attributes and on the templating engine you would prefer (have a look at haml).

Comment: thank you very much, this was absolutely helpful. I`ll follow these general steps and hopefully finish my small project.  I appreciate a lot your time and patience!